# Twitter button doesn't appear on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, firefox, twitter

Why isn't the Twitter button showed when dealing with `ng-show` on Firefox only?

```
    <div ng-show="isTwitterScriptLoaded">
      <a href="https://twitter.com/Example" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-size="large">Follow @Example</a>
    </div>
```

[Demo Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ou5wcNzJokgRe3QKiFSt?p=preview)

On Chrome or Safari, the button appears.
On Firefox, it doesn't (without any set plugins) and no console errors.

If I remove the `ng-show`, it works on every browser.
Weird.

Comment: Works fine once I disable tracking protection (had to open the frame in a tab to get the option)

Comment: I disabled it too, but still doesn't appear with the ng-show.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 8.1 Pro with Firefox 43.0.1, it appears.

Comment: Please don't add taglines to answers.  It's [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) and annoying.

Comment: It works fine with chrome, Opera shows twitter but fb is empty rectangle, Firefox is empty for both and IE showed twitter and empty fb rectangle but on reload twitter is not appearing.